# Unable to retrieve my A360 HUB on getHubs call

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

When I use a demo app that has a web login page, it will detect both my personal A360 hub and our BIM360 hub.
When I use two-legged authentication with my clientId and secret, and call getHubs, it will only return my BIM 360 hub.
I also have a question regarding getHubs: I try to also specify username and password on the Configuration parameter on the gethubs call, in order to have the personal hub included, but they do not seem to be in use. If I specify wrong username or password it will not generate errors.

On the API basics page, it is stated:
For BIM 360 Team, Fusion Team, and A360 Personal, end users need to provide 3-legged authentication for your app to access the data.

So I might need to use 3 legged rather than 2 legged I guess.

I should point out that this is a server app, so I will try not to have an interactive login, but use predefined user + password.
The ThreeLeggedApi requires a returnUrl, so I'm not sure if this will work for me.

Comment: The solution I've found is this:
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/expanding-net-desktop-apps-cloud-sample-code

To access A360, you must use 3-legged authentication and a web page, but at least you can store the token and use auto renew, so you only need to login once.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, to access the BIM360 Team (A.K.A A360 Team), you must use 3-legged token.

Please check tutorials here to learn how to play with 3-legged authorization:

1. http://learnforge.autodesk.io/
2. https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/get-3-legged-token/
3. https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/get-3-legged-token-implicit/

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, to access A360 I used this application as base, although it is not ideal for a server solution. The auto renew token is working well, though.
https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/data.management-csharp-desktop.sample